# What's wrong with my factoring?

Tags: factoring

[image: Hopfully this is cleaner]

Khan Academy tells me I have to factor $-28$ into $2 \times  k \times (-14)$ but I'm pretty sure $-2 \times k \times 14$ is acceptable.

Comment: Do you think you can write this out more clearly? It is hard to understand the question?

Comment: The two expressions at the end of your question are equal. If one is acceptable the other should be. I didn't read any of the handwriting.

Comment: $2\cdot k\cdot (-14) = (-2)\cdot k\cdot 14 = -28k = 7\cdot (-4)\cdot k = \cdots$ there are many ways to write things

Comment: @burt I edited the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: much better! Do you know how to type the math equations on this site? You can put your problem straight in instead of doing it this way.

Comment: Sort of. I could also screenshot the question. Is there anything wrong with pictures?

Comment: Your page is not at all clear  what question you were answering, nor what answer you supplied.  When I looked at it I thought that $k=-14$ would not make the expression undefined because $k+14$ had be canceled higher up.  It is much better to write it up with some words explaining what you are doing.

Comment: Agreed. Pictures make it less clear and harder to understand. I believe people are more likely to take it seriously when fully written out.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer and Khan Academy's are equivalent. You can rewrite the $-28k$ as $(-2)(14)(k)$ or $(2)(-14)(k)$.

However, I think you ran into a problem when you factored $\dfrac{3(k^2-2(14)(k)+14^2)}{-4(k+14)(k-14)}$. Essentially when factoring the numerator, you are finding two numbers that multiply to $14^2$ and add to the coefficient of the middle term, $(-2)(14)=-28$. This would be $-14$ and $-14$, as $-14-14=-28$ and $(-14)^2=(14^2)$. So the numerator would factor to $3(k-14)(k-14)$, which would cancel with the $(k-14)$ in the denominator, not the $(k+14)$. This gives you $-\dfrac{3(k-14)}{4(k+14)}$.

Comment: Oh, I see! I must have missed the sigh on -2! Oops.